# gem installation ok but not with bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, pusher

I am trying to install the pusher-client gem.

I've put this in my Gemfile:

```
gem "pusher-client",:git=>"git://github.com/logankoester/pusher-client.git"
```

bundle install is ok

But when I start the app:

```
/Users/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': no such file to load -- pusher/client (LoadError)
from /Users/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `rescue in block in require'
from /Users/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
from /Users/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Users/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /Users/thomas/Documents/TweetTv/server/tvtweet/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `require'
from /Users/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It seems to be linked to the - in the gem name, but other gem install correctly.

Any help or suggestion greatly appreciate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `git` path is wrong. If you go to [the repository](https://github.com/logankoester/pusher-client) on GitHub you'll see the code has moved to [here](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-ruby-client).

You should do this in your `Gemfile` instead:

```
gem 'pusher-client', :git => "git://github.com/pusher/pusher-ruby-client.git"
```